# How to deploy symlinked react javascript files to appear in the Docker container

Tags: django, reactjs, docker

I have a Django as backend and React as frontend project running inside Docker containers.

Currently, I have all the Django and react code all in the same repo. And the project works as expected when testing at http://localhost:8000/frontend which will hit the template (`index.html` under the `/frontend/templates/frontend` which in turn will reference `/frontend/static/dist/main.js`)

So as it is right now, the project works with Docker.

The project is structured as thus:

```
project_root
     |
     |---frontend (this is a Django app which contains the react files)
     |      |--- static
     |      |      |--- dist
     |      |              |--- main.js
     |      |              
     |      |--- templates
     |             |--- frontend
     |                     |--- index.html (this references the static/dist/main.js)
     |
     |
     |---... more Django apps
     |
     |--- compose
             |
             |---local
                   |
                   |---- django
                            |---- Dockerfile
                            |---- start
```

Currently, my Dockerfile under the `/compose/local/django` looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client \
  # git
  && apk add --no-cache git

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/project.local.txt

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

### Objective

I would like to have my react code and my Django code as separate repos. Because it would be easier to have separate CI/CD and unit testing for frontend React code and backend Django code.

### What I tried

1. have a separate project folder meant just for the frontend react code and therefore it will live as its own git repo
2. symlink inside the Django project such that `/frontend/static/dist` points to the React project with the same folder name

The complaints I get from the browser is that `/frontend/static/dist/main.js` is missing.

When I check the symlinked, the main.js is definitely there. So I think somehow when the Docker container is built, the files didn't get copied over?

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `separate CI/CD` ending up with a single image? Keep those (front) files outside, deploy them separately. Why would you need to redeploy Django image after frontend changes not related to back modifications?

Comment: >Keep those (front) files outside, deploy them separately.  Can you elaborate a bit more about this?

Comment: Django does not need frontend files, Django will not serve any static files on prod - webserver will. So why would you put them inside this image?

Comment: Initially, when i started, I was ignorant what's the best way and i stumbled into this setup and it works. Now I want to improve by separating the react code and django code into separate repos while still able to deploy in production. Hence I asking here for help.

Comment: Are you running Django in prod with DEBUG=True? If not, then Django is not even trying to serve static files. And should not. Your static files must (ok, highly recommended) be served by webserver (Nginx, apache) without involving backend at all. `static` files are _static_. They don't need interpreter, they don't need any "images" and containerization - just copy them to prod and point specific nginx location to the folder with these files.

Comment: Once again, in prod, with appropriate (recommended) config Django will never know if any static files even exist. So why would you mix them into single image? You may try thinking further - about to deploy static files to separate server, like CDN concept. You were talking about `separate CI/CD` - so make them **separate**. Don't include **frontend** bundle into **backend** image. Do build them separately, do **deploy** them separately.

Comment: i have currently four containers in the prod environment. nginx, postgres, django, redis. I have no nginx running on the host. So do you suggest i have another container just for the react codes? By the way, the Django does serve the template file index.html

Comment: Why would plain text static files need a container? I have answered this question literally in the comment before the previous one.